# Man of Steel "Fate of your planet" trailer - high pitch whine?

Tags: trailer, noise

Hey,

I watched Man of Steel's newest trailer and noticed a high pitch whine during the voice over. Did this slip past editors? It's very loud around the 47-48 second mark.

Or am I missing something and this was in some way intentional?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlOF03DUoWc

Here's a screenshot of the voice in Voxengo Span. The high frequency signal is peaking at around 15.7 kHz.

[image: Screenshot]

PS. I'm not pointing fingers or anything, I'm just genuinely curious!

Comment: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3661/if-youre-a-sound-designer-of-a-movie-do-you-have-total-supervision-over-what-th

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm probably one of the best people to answer this since I did the editorial prep for the trailer, and worked on the feature. (Zack has had us, the feature crew, involved in his trailers since 300. As was mentioned, more typically, feature crews aren't involved in trailers.)

Zod's dialog was taken directly from the feature dialog stem. In the film, Zod is transmitting this message to Earth. We left in the tone that you refer to because it worked well with the messed up, distorted nature of his transmission. I get that the trailer takes it somewhat out of context so it doesn't work in the same way. But, in short, it's not a mistake.

And @sound designer is right. The synth tone that @bryce mentioned is a sound that I came up with for the big Kryptonian weapon at the end of the film, that Junkie XL, one of Hans' close collaborators, integrated into the score throughout the film.

Comment: @EricN, dude - rockin' answer! 

Comment: Great! Thanks for answering! I'm really glad  that someone who worked on it came here and answered my question. Shows how great the SSD community is! 

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question and keen observation.  I wonder if it could be an issue with the upload/conversion to YouTube format.  Also, totally off-topic observation, but I just love that synth (40 seconds in) in the music from that trailer.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty good. It sounds like a saturated and filtered reese to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a piece of sound design by Eric Norris and Scott Hecker which was incorporated into the score

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page here. I'm talking about a high frequency signal, peaking at around 15.7kHz. Here's a screenshot of the spectrum analyzer: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48858350/man-of-steel.PNG

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to me like the beeping of a TV screen that was on during the recording of the voice...